# How do you loop through a list of objects and get a specific attribute?

Tags: python, for-loop, object

I have this code, but whenever I run it, I only get 9. I am pretty new to python so I am not 100% sure if the .weight part is correct, but if it is then I have no idea what is wrong. The parameters for patient are: name, id, dob, height, weight

```
from func import Patient

p1 = Patient("John", 131, "03/09/03", 5.2, 155)
p2 = Patient("Josh", 151, "05/18/05", 5.8, 195)
p3 = Patient("Jacob", 179, "12/14/09", 6.5, 105)

patientList = [p1, p2, p3]

def getWeight(weight):
  for i in range(len(patientList)):
    if weight == patientList[i].weight:
        return patientList[i]
    else:
        return 9

print(getWeight(105))
```

Comment: why you need to loop with index? loop the array

Comment: post the `Patient` class definition, because `getWeight` looks like it should work

Comment: @flaxon I tried. Whenever I do that i get: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Patient"

Comment: @BatWannaBe the Patient Class is pretty simple just: class Patient:

    def __init__(self, name, idNumber, DOB, height, weight):
        self.name = name,
        self.idNumber = idNumber,
        self.DOB = DOB,
        self.height = height,
        self.weight = weight

Comment: you did no pass in the function patientList

Comment: what @flaxon means is you could've written `for patient in patientList:`, `if weight == patient.weight:`, `return patient`. But this edit won't fix your problem, it's just style.

Comment: he is not testing the write number, in your list you dont have 105

Comment: @BatWannaBe, i don't think getweight works

Comment: @flaxon I am trying to find 105 in a specific patient from the list. Each patient has attributes like height, weight, etc. I am trying to loop through the list and find a patient who has the same weight as the one specified

Comment: my bad i was mixing up

Comment: oh I see the error, you're returning on the first iteration when you don't get a match. You just need to return only when you get a match, and if you don't, return a 9 after the loop.

Comment: @johndaly69, please don't cram code into a comment. As you can see, it is nearly impossible to read. And with a language like Python that is sensitive to whitespace, it _is_ impossible to read without ambiguity. Instead, please [edit] your question. All critical information should be included there as comments can be deleted at any time for any reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your returning too early, you should loop first the whole array, then return 9 if not found. if you found you return right away.

you probably want this

```
def getWeight(weight):
    for p in patientList:
        if weight == p.weight:
            return p
        
    return 9
```

the above will return the first patient found with that weight.
But i think you would want to return a list of all patient instances in a list

```
def getWeight(weight):
    return [p for p in patientList if weight == p.weight]
```

Comment: I am not sure if its a problem in my IDE or what but this also return 9 for me??//// edit this returns <func.Patient object at 0x000001C6365D1C10> instead of 9. How can I get this to return a number?

Comment: it was based on your code.. what data you want to return?

Comment: this is the instance of your class

Comment: if you want the name for example use `return p.name` (not sure how you named your parameters, as i did not see your class)

Comment: I am pretty sure this is correct, but this is like the str value I think. If I put return int(p) it gives me a type error. I was just trying to get the int version of the return. Ex: print(getWeight(105))

Comment: Ok I think I got the hang of it. I just had to specify p.name, p.id, etc. thanks for your help

Comment: please explain me what the function has to return do you want it to filter all instances with this weight?

Comment: what happen if you have 2 instances with the same weight?

the current code wii return the first

Comment: Yes the code gives me back just the first instance

Comment: Also, whenever I run the code, it prints back: '(('John',), (131,))' How can I get rid of the commas and apostrophes? Just get the plain text

Comment: `def getWeight(weight):
    return [p for p in patientList if weight == p.weight]`

this will return a array with all instances that have this weight

Comment: it seems that its a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Patient:
    def __init__(self, name, idNumber, DOB, height, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.idNumber = idNumber
        self.DOB = DOB
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
    
p1 = Patient("John", 131, "03/09/03", 5.2, 155)
p2 = Patient("Josh", 151, "05/18/05", 5.8, 195)
p3 = Patient("Jacob", 179, "12/14/09", 6.5, 105)

patientList = [p1, p2, p3]

def getWeight(weight):
    outlist=[]
    for i in range(len(patientList)):
        if weight == patientList[i].weight:
            outlist.append(patientList[i].name)
            outlist.append(patientList[i].idNumber)
            outlist.append(patientList[i].DOB)
            outlist.append(patientList[i].height)
            outlist.append(patientList[i].weight)
            return outlist
    return 9

print(getWeight(105))

#['Jacob', 179, '12/14/09', 6.5, 105]
```

also in the future, you might want to consider solving the problem using pandas, like so:

```
import pandas

mydata = pandas.DataFrame([['John', 131, '03/09/03', 5.2, 155]
        ,['Josh', 151, '05/18/05', 5.8, 195]
        ,['Jacob', 179, '12/14/09', 6.5, 105]
],columns=['name', 'idNumber', 'DOB', 'height', 'weight'])

def getWeight(weight):
    return mydata.loc[mydata['weight'] == weight]

print(getWeight(105))
```